# Cannot get request body from form in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, forms, sinatra

I have a form submission in `Sinatra` that's not showing any received params.  `Chrome` is showing the form submission payload as proper, so the form is fine.  It's just not making it through to Sinatra for some reason.  Status code `200`.  I don't know what to post here.  My route has `puts params` as first entry in the route and it's showing up empty.

Any ideas how I can fix this?  I am thinking something is interrupting params before they can be used.

Here is the form and the post route:

```
<form method="post" class="form" name="carrier" id="form1" action="/login">
    <div class="row align-items-center">
        <div class="col-auto">
            <label for="s_uname" class="col-form-label">Username</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="s_uname" name="s_uname" required="" value="">
        </div>

        <div class="col-auto">
            <label for="s_pw" class="col-form-label">Password</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="s_pw" name="s_pw" required="" value="">
        </div>
        
                <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="s_type" value="carrier">

        <div class="col-auto">
            <button type="submit" id="mybutton1" class="btn btn-primary">Log in</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>


post "/login" do
  puts '/login here'
  puts params
  (other logic)
  erb :"account/login"
end
```

Comment: try `puts request.body`   docs here: https://rubydoc.info/gems/sinatra  (search for "Accessing the Request Object" title)

Comment: @num8er `App 22137 output: #<Rack::Lint::Wrapper::InputWrapper:0x000000010803b7a0>`  Also `body_content = request.body.read
  puts body_content` returns empty.

Answer (score 1):

I was using `Rack::Lint` which was not happy but not reporting anything in the logs.  I turned it off and it worked.